# android : format date

Tags: android, date

how to get the format of this string of date:

```
20121102010000 +0100
```

I try many possibilities of format but there are wrong and don't give the good date.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");


Date d;
try {
    d = format.parse(mydate);
    System.out.println(d);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Look at your format string - it has dashes and colons in. Now look at your sample value...

Comment: ... now back on your format string, sadly it's not match ...(taken from Old Spice commercial, sorry, ICNR)

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss z");
```

That's what I think after looking at [this table](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).